# Is it possible to use a context inside another context with react (hooks)?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-context

When I have two contexts, where one is inside another one:

```
  ...
    <ContextOne.Provider value={valueOne}>
      <ContextTwo.Provider value={valueTwo}>
        {children}
      </ContextTwo.Provider>
    </ContextOne.Provider>
  ...
```

Is it possible that `ContextTwo` now uses `ContextOne`:

```js
// ContextTwo.jsx
...
const contextOne = useContext(ContextOne);
console.log(contextOne.valueOne); // returns undefined
...
```

Basically, `ContextOne` transforms `valueOne` into a state (`useState`) and `ContexTwo` needs to use the state.
In my case, the values of `contextOne` are somehow undefined, while there are no async operations at all. I thought this is possible since `ContextTwo.Provider` is inside `ContextOne.Provider`?

At this point, I don't really know if this just isn't possible or if there is something wrong with my code in general.

Comment: Try adding a second set of curly braces around your value prop. So value={{valueOne}}

Comment: This is just a minimal example. @Yoshi `contextOne` could also `return {valueOne}`, which would make this code valid, but the question is more general and not only based on this minimal example anyway.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, its possible, you need to `useContext` within `ContextTwo` wrapper, for example:

```
const ContextOne = createContext();
const ContextTwoInner = createContext();

const ContextTwo = ({ value, children }) => {
  const valueOne = useContext(ContextOne);
  console.log(valueOne);

  return (
    <ContextTwoInner.Provider value={value}>
      {children}
    </ContextTwoInner.Provider>
  );
};

// For OP's code to work
ContextTwo.Provider = ContextTwo;


// Logs valueOne
const App = () => {
  return (
    <ContextOne.Provider value={valueOne}>
      <ContextTwo.Provider value={valueTwo}>
        <div>Hello</div>
      </ContextTwo.Provider>
    </ContextOne.Provider>
  );
};
```

[image: Edit fancy-cherry-cy3mq]